# Как подставить нужный элемент?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нашел на этом же форуме такое чудо:

```
тут http://codepen.io/DavidKern/pen/emjYzb
```

у меня есть файл php с содержанием:

```
echo rand(1, 4);
```

Этот файл вызывается через ajax и берется значение. Допустим что цвета колеса это цифры (1, 2, 3, 4).

Суть вопроса: как мне остановить колесо, скажем после 5 оборотов на нужном номере цвета ?

Пробовал по времени, но оно не работает стабильно, есть погрешности, а именно хотел узнать за сколько времени проходит полный оборот одной четверти, а потом просто создать 4 условия. Но там нужно время в микросекундах что ли, а setTimeout этого не понимает и использует только мили. var `rTime = 250;`

Comment: покажите. что вы пытались сделать сами

Comment: @Grundy Дописал.

Comment: я имел ввиду код. Суть в том, что анимации указана длительность 2.25s, это оборот от 0 до 720 градусов, чтобы передать значение секунд в setTimeout необходимо их умножить на 1000

Comment: @Grundy Времени анимации я пока не менял. Но в дальнейшем хочу ее уменьшать теми же средствами jquery что бы в конце замедлять его движение. Что-то типа эффекта рулетки. Или это в данном примере не возможно ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, наговнокодил как следует, но работает. Делюсь решением.

Как подсказал Dmitry OnGamer, нужно было взглянуть на transform. Покуртил я колесо, записал все положения каждого цвета, из этого вышла не хитрая ф-я.

```
function stopRoll (numstop) {

    var sTime = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + 50;

    var tt = setInterval(function() {

       var split = $('#spin').css('transform').split(",");

       if(numstop == 1) {
            if(split[0].replace(/matrix\(/g,"") > 0 && split[1] > 0 && split[2] < 0 && split[3] > 0) {
                $('#spin').css('animationPlayState', 'paused');
                $('#spaner').text("Win 1");
                clearInterval(tt);
            }
       }
       if(numstop == 2) {
            if(split[0].replace(/matrix\(/g,"") < 0 && split[1] > 0 && split[2] < 0 && split[3] < 0) {
                $('#spin').css('animationPlayState', 'paused');
                $('#spaner').text("Win 2");
                clearInterval(tt);
            }
       }
       if(numstop == 3) {
            if(split[0].replace(/matrix\(/g,"") < 0 && split[1] < 0 && split[2] > 0 && split[3] < 0) {
                $('#spin').css('animationPlayState', 'paused');
                $('#spaner').text("Win 3");
                clearInterval(tt);
            }
       }
       if(numstop == 4) {
            if(split[0].replace(/matrix\(/g,"") > 0 && split[1] < 0 && split[2] > 0 && split[3] > 0) {
                $('#spin').css('animationPlayState', 'paused');
                $('#spaner').text("Win 4");
                clearInterval(tt);
            }
       }

    },sTime);

}
```

Вызываю я ее когда колесо наше прокрутилось и кручу до тех пор пока не найду нужный пиксел для остановки. Добавил немного рандома в `setInterval`, что-бы не останавливалось каждый раз на одном месте.

Всем спасибо !

Answer (score 1):

Привязываясь ко времени точного результата будет добиться практически не реально. Посмотрите значения `circle.css('transform')` и после какого-то времени исполнения анимации вставляйте проверку в каком диапазоне поставить анимацию на паузу.

Comment: Вот что вывел transmorm: matrix(0.962936, -0.26973, 0.26973, 0.962936, 0, 0). Я не очень понимаю как по нему проверить позицию. Не подскажете ?